# Можно ли подменить адрес дескриптора указателя?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin

Код конечно же нерабочий, просто отображает смысл вопроса. Возможно ли сделать что-то наподобие такого?

```
var
  P: Pointer;
  S: String

implementation

procedure EncodeAddress(var Pr: Pointer);
begin
  @Pr := @Pr+10;
end;

procedure DecodeAddress(var Pr: Pointer);
begin
  @Pr := @Pr-10;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  New(P);
  S := 'Simple string';
  P := Pointer(S);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Адрес первого символа строки ' + IntToStr(Integer(P)));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Адрес дескриптора строки: ' + IntToStr(Integer(Addr(P))));
  EncodeAddress(P);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Новый адрес дескриптора строки: ' + IntToStr(Integer(Addr(P))));
  DecodeAddress(P);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Прежний адрес дескриптора строки: ' + IntToStr(Integer(Addr(P))));
end;
```

Comment: в чем вопрос то, про арифметику указателей, или про что? адреса можно складывать и вычитать, это в целом частая операция

Comment: @teran  `@Pr := @Pr+10;` -  [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(39): E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to

Comment: дак что у вас `@` то делает? вы используете этот оператор с какой целью? просто увеличивайте или уменьшайте указатель, возможно потребуется включить `{$POINTERMATH ON}`.

Comment: зы: вам не надо делать `new(p)` это бессмысленно. Указатели на строки обычно это `pchar`. Приводить адрес к `integer` не корректно, используйте `NativeInt`. Строка это ссылочный тип, в отрицательном смещении от данных она хранит число ссылок и длину.

Comment: @teran дак а что же вы сразу не указали на ошибку в коде. Привели бы пару строчек кода в качестве примера, было бы намного понятней. В моем случае совсем не важно, что будет хранится в смещенном диапазоне. +10 - 10 взято условно, для примера, оно может быть +1000 или x10 и т.д.. Мне нужно что бы после кодирования адреса по этому дескриптору уже нельзя было получить данных содержащихся в переменной.

Comment: Нужно просто явное приведение типа. Брать указатель на указатель (@) совсем не нужно. `p:=Pointer(NativeUInt(p)+10);`

Comment: Можно ещё проще, вроде: `p := PByte(p) + 10;`. Но вообще это сомнительное решение непонятной задачи ИМХО.

Answer (score 2):

переменная указателя содержит адрес памяти на которую он ссылается. Адрес это число. Поэтому для изменения значения указателя, просто приведите его с целочисленному значению, проведите нужные арифметические операции, и затем впишите значение обратно, опять же с помощью явного приведения типов.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses System.SysUtils;

const ptrOffset = 10;

    procedure encodePtr(var p : pointer);
    begin
        p := pointer(NativeInt(p) - ptrOffset);
    end;

    procedure decodePtr(var p : pointer);
    begin
        p := pointer(NativeInt(p) + ptrOffset);
    end;


var s : string;
    p : pointer;
begin
    s := 'test string';
    p := pointer(s);
    writeln('init p: ', IntToHex(NativeInt(p), 8));

    encodePtr(p);
    writeln('encode p: ', IntToHex(NativeInt(p), 8));

    decodePtr(p);
    writeln('decode p: ', IntToHex(NativeInt(p), 8));

    readln;
end.
```

С типизированными указателями работать несколько проще, там можно сразу использовать арифметические операции и функции `inc`, `dec`, учитывающие размер типа данных.

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Но я спрашивал про изменение адреса самой ссылки т.е. дескриптора, а не адреса первого символа строки.

Comment: указатель это такая же переменная как и остальные. Она сама размещена по какому-то адресу, а значением этой переменной является адрес памяти, на которую он ссылается. Строка в этом примере никуда не девается и адрес свой не меняет. Меняется значение адреса, т.е значение переменной-указателя. В этой связи мне не ясно вообще, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Изменить адрес самой переменной? это бессмысленно. Можете нарисовать схемой. а слово "дескриптор" тут вообще не уместно, ибо обычно применяется для именования структур, содержащих описание некого отрытого/запущенного ресурса.